# cloudscraper exception but is not the captcha one

Tags: python, web-scraping, cloudflare

I had a problem with downloading a file with request lib because of cloudflare so I wanted to use  cloudscraper.
I tried different things but I always have the same result. the code that downloads the file is this one

```
    scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
    response = scraper.get(Linkds).text
    open("DownloadedFile.torrent", "wb").write(response.content)
    print('pass download')
```

the error I get is this one:

cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) version.

the searches I found that people always talked about the same problem but it says version 2 captcha challenge. which is not like the error I get. here what I searched.

https://github.com/ptrstn/dailyblink/issues/7
[cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352220/cloudscraper-exceptions-cloudflarechallengeerror-detected-a-cloudflare-version)
https://www.reddit.com/r/webscraping/comments/xj9ykg/python_scraping_rent_properties_getting_blocked/

I also tried using the webbrowser lib but it doesn't help that much because i need to handle the file internally for automation purposes. (I think I could use an AHK script to do that, but at that point is just overly complicated and way harder to setup for me)

I tried tinkering with the request lib but I couldn't get it to work either(it only showed the cloudflare protection)

(not sure if it matter but the program is a discordbot/tkinterUI downloader that downloads the torrent file into a folder)

the bot only needs to work with https://nhentai.net/ the idea is that you go into a link like https://nhentai.net/g/111111/ then you add download to the end like this

(messageuwu is the link) https://nhentai.net/g/111111/

```
Linkds=messageuwu+'download'
```

and it downloads the torrent file. the problem is, cloudflare. with the browser lib works kinda right(because of automation problem is not practical) I don't know what else to try.